# How to Load an external Javascript and HTML file in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have created a HTML and corresponding .js files seperately.

Now, what I require is to load them in my existing angular project, so that for example, I can open the new HTML and .js as:

localhost:portnumber/HTML file name - or something similar

I have learned over internet to mention the js file in angular.json, but what about the html file ?  How do I load it? Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you asking how to serve an HTML document with some JS that have nothing Angular related in them at all from the Angular dev server?

Comment: @Quentin yes absolutely

Comment: Sounds like something better handled by deploying everything to a non-development server.

Comment: @Quentin Not sure what you last comment means, however, I have come accross this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416871/routing-to-static-html-page-in-angular-6

And have done these changes:
      "src/all.html",
              {
                "glob": "all.html",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/home/"
              }

in angular.json.

But not sure how to fire up the final url.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding glob in angular.json - just in case anyone needs for future reference.